# Writing Byte Values in Bitmap Header To File

Tags: c++, bitmap, hex

I'm trying to write a bitmap header to file. For the moment, I just want to write the header without any pixel data. I'm basing the values on [this](http://www.daubnet.com/en/file-format-bmp), [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/4307/), and [this](http://www.garybeene.com/code/gbsnippets_gbs_00415.htm). I have the following function for composing a standard, uncompressed 24bit RGB bitmap header as a uint8_t:

```
uint8_t* make_rgb24_bmp_header(int data_size, int width, int height)
    {
        uint8_t* ret = new uint8_t[BITMAP_HEADER_SIZE];

        //signature
        ret[0] = 'B';
        ret[1] = 'M';

        //2-3-4-5
        write_32bit_num_to_data(ret + 2, data_size); //file size in bytes as hexadecimal

        ret[6] = 0;
        ret[7] = 0;
        ret[8] = 0;
        ret[9] = 0;
        //specifies the starting offset of the image - 54 bytes in.
        ret[10] = 0x36;
        ret[11] = 0;
        ret[12] = 0;
        ret[13] = 0;
        //specifies header size - 40 bytes
        ret[14] = 28;
        ret[15] = 0;
        ret[16] = 0;
        ret[17] = 0;

        //18,19,20,21 - image width
        write_32bit_num_to_data(ret + 18, width);
        //20,23,24,25 - image height
        write_32bit_num_to_data(ret + 22, height);

        //planes - 1
        ret[26] = 1;
        ret[27] = 0;
        //bpp - 24
        ret[28] = 18;
        ret[29] = 0;
        //compression - 0
        ret[30] = 0;
        ret[31] = 0;
        ret[32] = 0;
        ret[33] = 0;

        //34,35,36,37
        write_32bit_num_to_data(ret + 34, data_size); //compressed size - no compression here, so same as data_size
        //38,39,40,41
        write_32bit_num_to_data(ret + 38, 2835); //Horizontal resolution in pixels per meter
        //42,43,44,45
        write_32bit_num_to_data(ret + 42, 2835); //Vertical resolution in pixels per meter

        //number of colors - not needed as we're not using a color palette
        ret[46] = 0;
        ret[47] = 0;
        ret[48] = 0;
        ret[49] = 0;

        //important colors - not needed
        ret[50] = 0;
        ret[51] = 0;
        ret[52] = 0;
        ret[53] = 0;

        return ret;
    }
```

I save it in the following way:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    uint8_t* header = utils::make_rgb24_bmp_header(1244214, 720, 576);

    ofstream out;

    out.open("sample_header", ios::out | ios::binary);

    out.write((char*)&header, 54);

    out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting the first two bytes of the file to be 44 4d, but they come out as F0 E0 when I open the output file in Bless. Clearly I've missed something essential (I can also see that the rest of the values are incorrect), and understanding where I'm going wrong with the first two bytes should help me with the rest. How do I go about getting the output I expect?

Comment: Change `out.write((char*)&header, 54);` to `out.write((char*)header, 54);`.

Comment: `ret[14] = 28`... `28` or `0x28`? Also `ret[28] = 18;`? Either use all hex or all decimal, trying to mix will make you forget things like the hexadecimal `0x` prefix.

Comment: Such a simple thing to miss! You're right. I was writing the memory around the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong value to out.write:

```
out.write((char*)header, 54);
```

By passing it as &header you are trying to write out values where the pointer is stored rather than where it points to (and where your data is).